# How do I bring a variable's value from one function to another?

Tags: c++, function, variables, dynamic

Could someone please explain how to bring a value from a variable in one function to another function. I know that as soon as the function ends that variable's value in the function is cleaned out. But how do I tell it not to do that.

I am trying to bring the `int ppl;` value from the candidates function into the votes function. But as you can see it won't do it on its own.

```
void candidates()
{           
    int ppl;
    cout << "Hello please how many candidates are there?: ";
    std::cin >> ppl;
    string *cans = new string[ppl];
    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please type in the last name of candidate number: " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> cans[i];cout  << endl << endl;
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < ppl; a++)
    {
        cout << cans[a] << endl << endl;
    }
}

void votes()
{               
    int *vote = new int[ppl];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Look into return values and reference variables. [This site should help a lot while you're learning!](http://www.learncpp.com/)

Comment: You should look at how to pass **arguments** to functions and use **return** values.

Comment: `void candidates(int &ppl)` and `void votes(int const ppl)`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you want is probably:

```
std::vector<string> gather_data() {...}

void use_data( std::vector<string> data ) { ... }
```

And then you can do:

```
auto data = gather_data();
use_data( data );
```

It would be better practice to make sure that use_data can't modify its argument, and that this argument is passed by reference.  So:

```
void use_data( const std::vector<string>& data ) { ... }
```

A more advanced pattern would be to use a class:

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<string> data;
public:
    void gather() {...}
    void use() {...}
}

Foo myFoo;
myFoo.gather();
myFoo.use();
```

In this case you can see that `Foo`'s instance methods have access to its `data`.

You certainly don't want to be using global variables without very good reason.

However, if you're asking a question at this basic level, it means you need to [read a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

You will find it is impractical to try learning what is one of the most difficult languages around just by asking questions. Each answer will raise 10 more questions.

Comment: @juanchopanza: fixed. The main point I'm trying to address is that whatever the answer is, it will be of little value. There is a more immediate problem than *"not understanding parameters"*, namely *"lack of a structured approach to learning"*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`:

```
int candidates()
{
    int ppl;
    std::cin >> ppl;
    ...
    return ppl;
}
```

Function candidates() now receives an `int` so now you can do this:

```
void votes()
{
    int *vote = new int[candidates()];
}
```

You can also use global variables, or pass the variable `ppl` as `int&` to function `candidates()` as argument, so `ppl` had to be created out of the function (let's say in main function), therefore it's available for every function you need.